# Certification: Developer or Developer Plus

Tags: certification

I want to apply for magento certification. I can see from the official website: https://magento.com/training/catalog/certified-developer-and-developer-plus#.VrsLuFjhXIU
that i can write developer and developer plus. I have few questions to ask:

1. Can i take Developer plus without Developer certification?
2. In my company, we will never use the Magento Enterprise edition. So, can you suggest Developer or Developer plus certification, which one would fit for me?
3. Normally how much time to complete the study and give a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can i write Developer plus without Developer certification?**

*Answer: is Yes,you can write Developer plus without Developer certification*

**Normally how much time to complete the study and give a test?**

*Answer: It is depend on how much time,You will take time to study..Basically it may be take  1month as per as my concept*

Answer (score 2):

1. You can take the Developer Plus without the Developer certification, however the plus is including Magento Enterprise and if you don´t use it I don´t know if its useful for you.
2. I suggest you take the normal developer one as this covers Magento Community
3. It depends how much you study but there is a 30 days study guide available here [Magestore Study Guide](http://www.magestore.com/magento-certification-study-guides.html)